# How to send an integer over a socket to a Java application using python?

Tags: java, python, sockets, integer, byte

I have a client in Python that sends data (preceded by a data length message):

```
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))
data = 'hello world'
s.sendall('%16s' % len(data)) #send data length
s.sendall(data) #send data
s.close()
```

And a server in Java that receives the data. The server uses [DataInputStream.readInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt%28%29) to read the data length before reading the data. However I seem to be getting really large numbers returned by readInt(). What is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java expects the binary representation of your integer. You can use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module to generate binary representations.

In your case, this would be:

```
import struct
s.sendall(struct.pack('i', len(data)))
```

Also make sure you use the correct [byte order](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). Java could be expecting network byte order.

Comment: Added a link to the byte order section. Java could be expecting network byte order

Answer (score 2):

As @mensi says, absent any other processing Java expects to receive the binary representation of the data, which differs from what Python is sending.  A common solution to this sort of issue is to [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) your data -- that is, to translate it into a format more suitable for network transmission, and reconstitute the data on the receiving side.

A common serialization format for which both Python and Java have support is [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).  Recent versions of Python have the `json` module as part of the standard library.